# Check out a Git repository with chef?

Tags: git, github, version-control, chef-infra

I have a Git repository I would like to check out onto a server. Is there a Chef recipe that does that?

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with Ruby, or just Git? Checking-out a repo doesn't change based on what the repo contains.

Comment: Andrew, you right, this is unrelated to ruby.

Comment: I guess this is helpful info: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Deploy+Resource

Comment: This works perfectly for public repos, but for private repos, you nee to add ssh_wrapper
to your code , so that it will take ssh key to your ssh call

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The git [SCM resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html) is probably what you're looking for. Simple resource usage example:

```
git "/path/to/check/out/to" do
  repository "git://github.com/opscode/chef.git"
  reference "master"
  action :sync
end
```

Also see "revision" attribute if you want to grab a specific branch.

Comment: A link describing the `git` resource specifically:
[http://docs.opscode.com/resource_git.html](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_git.html)

Comment: It should also be noted that one must have git installed prior to using the git resource. In a Chef cookbook you can either:
`package 'git' do
  action :install 
end`
or 
`include_recipe 'git::default'`
Make sure you also add `depends git` in your metadata.rb file if going with the second option.

Comment: References linked in the answer are no longer valid. Use the following:

https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html

Comment: Thanks @DanielBaker, I've updated the original answer with the corrected URL.